# Wordpress Site - pages have low text-HTML ratio

Tags: wordpress

I am having a problem with low text-to-HTML ratio of pages on wordpress sites.

I could not find a permanent solution in my research.

I use the Wp-Rocket plugin.
I removed unused css codes.
The theme is clean and I use little code.

I used the Fast Velocity Minify plugin to compress html, but it always breaks the site. I tested it on many themes.

Has anyone found a permanent solution?
My site: https://barisdayak.com/

I am looking for a permanent solution to the Wordpress - pages have low text-HTML ratio problem.

Comment: The issue you're having is caused by how the theme that you're using is built. If you're the developer this theme, then you can modify the HTML and CSS to fix the high amount of HTML. Otherwise, I wouldn't really bother with this as in practice, the user will notice little to nothing of the text-html ratio.